# Select query takes 3 seconds to pull 330 records. Need Optimization

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, performance, optimization

I have and normal select query that take nearly 3 seconds to execute (`Select * from users`). There are only 310 records in the user table.

The configuration of the my production server is

SQl Server Express Editon
Server Configuration  : Pentium 4 HT, 3 ghz , 2 GB ram

```
Column Nam  Type    NULL    COMMENTS
Column Nam              Type            NULL               
user_companyId          int         Not  Null
user_userId             int         Not Null Primary Column
user_FirstName          nvarchar(50)        Null                
user_lastName           nvarchar(60)        Null                
user_logon              nvarchar(50)        Null                
user_password           nvarchar(255)       Null                
user_emailid            nvarchar(255)       Null                
user_status             bit         Null                
user_Notification           bit         Null                
user_role               int         Null                
user_verifyActivation       nvarchar(255)       Null                
user_verifyEmail            nvarchar(255)       Null                
user_loginattempt           smallint        Null                
user_createdby          int         Null                
user_updatedby          int         Null                
user_createddate            datetime        Null                
user_updateddate            datetime        Null                
user_Department         nvarchar(1000)      Null                
user_Designation            nvarchar(1000)      Null
```

Comment: Show us the table structure! What indices do you have?

Comment: Does this happens when you write this query directly using Management studio?

Comment: Really, you have a *production* server running the *Express* edition. You are a brave soul :-)

Comment: @marc_s, I'd give you +1 if I could for using the word _indices_ instead of _indexes_, like the plebs ;-)

Comment: @ninesided: guess that's my two years of Latin showing its (late) impact :-) So it wasn't totally wasted after all :-)

Comment: @Dasharath: शो टेबल स्ट्रक्चर. (i.e. Show Table Structure)

Comment: @Pax : I've never used the express edition, but if it supports all the SQLs the "regular" version does, maybe this is a great way to "load test" applications! Is that a good use for express?

Comment: Does your 3s time include establishing the database connection, or is that time measured across an already existing connection?

Comment: @bevan: I am running this query through the management studio

Comment: @liao: posted the table structure in the post

Comment: @artyon: yes im querying through the management studio

Comment: Looks like you should attempt some self-help here. Have you tried http://msjawahar.wordpress.com/2007/11/23/why-is-sql-server-so-slow/ ?

Comment: All these people down talking the Express edition really confuses me.  From a performance standpoint it's only major drawbacks is it's memory and cpu usage limits, which for many small business applications is perfectly fine.  There is nothing about it that makes it unfit for production use.

Comment: @aaronis, if you want peak performance, you don't choose a DBMS that limits itself to 2G mem or a single core. You're right that it may be fine for small business apps however.

Answer (score 2):

Is anything else happening on this machine?

Even if you made worst possible data structure, SELECT * FROM Users should not take 3 seconds for 310 records. Either there is more (a lot more) records inside or there is some problem outside of SQL server (some other process blocking code or hardware issues).

Comment: Worst possible structure? Put three image columns on your table, and then fill them with 1.99GB files. That would take quite a while to return!

Comment: He could also have memory issues going on. Especially if Exchange Server is running on the same box and it's getting hit more than the web DB, causing the web DB to stay paged.

Comment: @Eric: My image of "worst possible structure" in 31-row table didn't include enormous field. My oversight. :)

Answer (score 2):

As there is no where clause this isn't down to indexes etc, Sql will do a full table scan and return all the data. I'd be looking at other things running on the machine, or SQL having run for a long time and used up a lot of VM. Bottom line is that this isn't a SQL issue - it's a machine issue.

Answer (score 1):

Well, indexes don't much matter here--you're getting a table scan with that query.

So, there are only a few other items that could be bogging this down. One is row size. What columns do you have? If you have tons of text or image columns, this could be causing a delay in bringing these back.

As for your hardware, what's your HDD's RPMs? Remember, this is reading off of a disk, so if there are any other IO tasks being carried out, this will obviously cause a performance hit.

Answer (score 1):

There's a number of things you should consider:

- Don't use the Express edition, it's probably called that for a reason. Go with a real DBMS (and, yes, this includes the non-express SQL Server).
- Use of `"select * from"` is always a bad idea unless you absolutely need every column. Change it to get only the columns you need.
- Are you using a `"where"` or "`order by"` clause. If so, you need to ensure you have indexes set up correctly (even for 330 rows, since tables always get bigger than you think).
- Use `EXPLAIN`, or whatever tool Microsoft provides as an equivalent. It will show you why the query is running slow.
- If your DB is on a different machine, there may be network issues (not necessarily problems, you may have stateful packet filters that slow down connections, for example).
- Examine the system loads of the boxes you're using. If there are other processes using a lot of CPU grunt or disk I/O, they may be causing slowdown.

Comment: IIRC, the database engine inside SQL Server Express is the same as that in the larger editions, just without some of the extra modules deployed, and with a limiter to stop the database growing larger than 2G. In other words, for this situation, use of Express isn't going to explain the slowness.

Comment: @pax: No I'm not using "order by" or "where" clause
DB is in same server as the application server

Comment: @Bevan: absolutely right - I don't see how switching to another SQL server edition would help in any way....

Comment: @Bevan, there are quite a few differences between Express and the others. See http://www.microsoft.com/Sqlserver/2005/en/us/compare-features.aspx for details. It may not be the specific cause of this problem but the scalability and performance issues alone (especially multi-core support) would convince me to steer clear of Express for production databases.

Comment: Bevan is absolutely correct, Express has the same engine as SQL Server. Technically the limits are 1GB of RAM and 4GB of data. It is a "real" DBMS.

Comment: No, I think we'll just have to agree to disagree on that one. The limit  of only being able to run on a single core is the killer to me. Have a look at all the questions on SO re DBMS performance - an artificial limit like single core (or memory/DB size for that matter) means Express is a developer-only variant for me. For production, I prefer something better.

Answer (score 0):

Without the table structure to know what your table looks like, we can't answer such a question....

What about not using `SELECT * FROM Users`, but actually specify which fields you really need from the table??

```
SELECT user_companyId, user_userId,
       user_FirstName, user_lastName, user_logon
FROM Users
```

How does that perform?? Do you still need 3 seconds for this query, or is this significantly faster?

If you really need all the users and all their attributes, then maybe that's just the time it takes on your system to retrieve that amount of data. The best way to speed up things is to limit the attributes retrieved (do you really need the user's photo??) by specifying a list of fields, and to limit the number of elements retrieved using a `WHERE` clause (do you REALLY need ALL users? Not just those that.........)

Marc

Comment: I need pretty much all columns. Even if I did select lesser columns I didnt think pulling 310 records with less data in each column will take 3 seconds.

Comment: The point just is: if you can skip a large column (e.g. a photo, or a long text field), it might just need to read less data, so if you have a slow HD and you need to read less data, your query will be faster. Also, even if you need all columns, specifying them explicitly in the SELECT will be faster since SQL Server doesn't need to do a column lookup first to figure out what columns are in your table.

Comment: E.g. if you could avoid retrieving the user_department and user_designation fields, both up to 2000 bytes each, that alone could save you several MB of data that doesn't need to be transferred

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is profile the server and also pay attention to what kinds of locks are occurring during the query.

If you are using any isolation level options, or the default, determine if you can lower the isolation level, which will decrease the locking occurring on the table.  The more locking that occurs, the more conflicts you will have where the query has to wait for other queries to complete.  However, be very careful when lowering the isolation level, because you need to understand how that will effect the data you get back.

Determine if you can add where criteria to your query.  Restricting the records you query can reduce locks.

Edit: If you find locking issues, you need to also evaluate any other queries that are being run.

Comment: Don't lower isolation levels without understanding the possible consequences. You may see uncommitted data and get inconsistent results. It probably won't matter that much with most management reports, since no-one in their right mind usually reads them, and those that do read them will make bad decisions no matter what the reports say :-)

Comment: That's why I made sure to say "you need to understand".  LOL@your management report note.  Even when they do read them they wouldn't know how to verify their correctness.

Answer (score 0):

If it's consistently 3 seconds, the problem isn't the query or the schema, for any reason that wouldn't be obviously irrational to the designer. I'd guess it's hardware or network issues. Is there anything you can do with the database that doesn't take 3 seconds? What do SET STATISTICS IO ON and SET STATISTICS TIME ON tell you? I bet there's nothing there that supports 3 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Without a better indexing strategy, leaving certain columns out will only reduce the impact on the network, which shouldn't be awfulf for only 310 rows. My guess is that it's a locking issue.

So consider using:

```
SELECT * FROM Users (NOLOCK);
```

This will mean that you don't respect any locks that are currently on the table by other connections. You may get 'dirty reads', seeing data which hasn't been committed yet - but it could be worthwhile from a performance perspective.

Let's face it - if you've considered the ramifications, then it should be fine...

Rob

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do for any performance problem is to be an execution plan for the query - this is a representation of what run path SQL server chooses when it executes your query. Best place to look for info on how to do this is Google - you want a statistics plan as it includes information about how many rows are returned.

This doesn't sound like a problem with the execution plan however, as the query is so simple - in fact I'm fairly sure that query counts as a "trivial plan", i.e. there is only 1 possible plan.

This leaves locking or hardware issues (is the query only slow on your production database, and is it always slow or does the execution time vary?) the query will attemp to get a shared lock on the whole table - if anyone is writing then you will be blocked from Reading until the writer is finished. You can check to see if this us the source of your problem by looking at the DMVs see http://sqllearningsdmvdmf.blogspot.com/2009/03/top-10-resource-wait-times.html

Finally, there are restrictions on SQL express in terms of CPU utilisation, memory use etc... What is the load on your server like? (operations per second)

Answer (score 0):

is there a possible way that the performance may degrade based on the column size (length of the data in the column)..

in your table u got last 2 columns with the size of NVARCHAR(1000), is it always filled with that amount of data..??

am not a sql expert, but consider the packetsize its about to return for 310 records with these 2 columns & without ll be different..

i saw similar post here in stack.. u can just go through this

[performance-in-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284609/performance-in-sql-mobile-with-one-big-column-thats-not-being-selected)